# Jupyter Notebook In Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed two versions of python in my system such as python 3.6 and python 3.
I am running a program in PyCharm which is running fine while the same script is not running in a Jupyter Notebook. The error shown:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

I had installed jupyter using anaconda.
The following are my questions:

1. How do I run a jupyter notebook for the same script?
2. Is my notebook not pointing to the same python version that I ran in PyCharm?
    If so, how can I change it to the appropriate python version?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sriyam\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://python.org')
```

Comment: How did you install selenium? if this error happens in PyCharm, you go to settings > project interpreter and then you select the interpreter that has selenium installed.

Answer (score 0):

have you install selenium

install it

try

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

if error pops up  again
try this

```
pip install selenium
```

note:-install it from conda prompt 
hope it may help